# How to create vertical scrollable area in SpriteKit (Step-by-Step)?

Tags: swift, scroll, sprite-kit, uikit

**Context**

I am developing a **SpriteKit** game and I want to add a **scrollable area** to it that displays certain items.(e.g. each item can consist of image and label). Below is a picture that depicts exactly what I am trying to accomplish: *you select the "basketball icon" and a list of potential balls are available to be scrolled through and selected* (further details after the picture)

[image]

With that in mind, I have seen several proposals to attain that goal but the majority of the posts are outdated and most of times not detailed enough for someone to execute. Some suggestions consist of:

1. Embed UIKit elements such as UIScrollView, UICollectionView or UITableView to your SKScene *(in this scenario I imagine my items mentioned above - image and label - instead of Skpritekit elements would need to be customised cells)*
2. Embed UIKit elements (same as above) to an SKNode overlay that sits on top of Scene
3. Use an SKCameraNode to "simulate" a scrollable behaviour that just follows touches and moves along a bigger Scene (e.g. 2 times the frame size - vertically) this way displaying other SpriteKit elements

That said, I am looking for step-by-step recommendations based on:

**(a)** own experience (e.g. providing code snippets as answer and/or GitHub examples that are similar)

**(b)** Available public tutorials (youtube / articles)

**(c)** Other format you see fit

Ultimately this post and answers can work out as a good foundation for all other people looking for similar implementations.

Thanks in advance for your time and effort. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

From my experience as a game developer, I recommend using [SwiftySKScrollView](https://github.com/crashoverride777/swifty-sk-scroll-view).

SwiftySKScrollView is a helper class to add a UIScrollView to your SpriteKit scenes. The helper will automatically forward button presses to the relevant SKScene and node subclasses. Easy to use and to implement.

Also, it's not worth it to use an SKCamera on this kind of game, also from experience. It will be pretty hard and time consuming for you to try and reproduce the scroll area with all its effects. And in the end, the SwiftySKScrollView which is a helper class to add a UIScrollView will look more smoother and natural.